# MongoDB validation part with any one of the field check

Tags: mongodb, validation, mongodb-query

Trying to figure out how to validate an array of object and map(key, value) pair

```
{
    "commonIdentification": {
        "CR": "BR",
        "SN": "NAVS87397394"
    }
    "digitalIdentiifcation": {
        "UUID": "326f040b-cf14-4cf9-9e67-57f7ca3ce1b2"
    }
}
```

Here , I want to add the validation like,

1. In commonIdentification with the presence of CR ,no need for digitalIdentiifcation's presence
2. In commonIdentification with the absence of CR, digitalIdentiifcation's 'UUID' field is required.

Can anyone please help on reformatting the validation part?I am struggling to validate based on the above points.

```
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    properties: {
      commonIdentification: {
        type: 'object',
        required: [
          'CR'
        ],
        properties: {
          CR: {
            type: 'string',
            description: 'CR is mandatory '
          }
        }
      }
    },
    type: 'object',
    required: [
      'commonIdentification',
      'digitalIdentiifcation'
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 $jsonSchema: {
type: 'object',
required: [
  'commonIdentification'
],
anyOf: [
  {
    required: [
      'digitalIdentiifcation'
    ]
  },
  {
    required: [
      'commonIdentification'
    ]
  }
],
properties: {
  commonIdentification: {
    type: 'object',
    anyOf: [
      {
        required: [
          'CR'
        ]
      },
      {
        required: [
          'SN'
        ]
      }
    ],
    properties: {
      SN: {
        type: 'string',
        description: 'SN or CR or digitalIdentiifcation is mandatory '
      },
      CR: {
        type: 'string',
        description: 'SN or CR or digitalIdentiifcation is mandatory '
      }
    },
    description: 'SN or CR or digitalIdentiifcation is mandatory '
  },
  digitalIdentiifcation: {
    description: 'digitalIdentiifcation'
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).